# Single pointer for linked list deletion function // is it possible

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

Currently, I am studying the **linked list structure**.

As I searched, linked list deletion function utilizing **'double pointer'**.
In below code, the node is successfully deleted by double pointer in delete function.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
    node* head;
    node* tail;
public:
    LinkedList()
    {
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
    }
    void add_node(int n)
    {
        node* temp = new node;
        temp->data = n;
        temp->next = nullptr;

        if(head == nullptr)
        {
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = temp;
            tail = tail->next;
        }
    }
    node* gethead()
    {
        return head;
    }
    void display(node * head)
    {
        if(head == nullptr)
        {
            cout << "nullptr : No data" << endl;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            node* temp;
            temp = head;
            while(temp != nullptr)
            {               
                cout << temp->data << endl;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }        
    }
    void del(node* head, int value)
    {       
        if(!head)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            node** nd = &head;
            while(*nd && (*nd)->data != value)
                nd = &(*nd)->next;
            if(*nd)
            {
                node* temp = *nd;
                *nd = (*nd)->next;
                delete temp;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "No matching data in the node" <<endl;
            }           
        }   
    }
};

int main()
{
    LinkedList la;
    la.add_node(10);
    la.add_node(20);
    la.add_node(30);
    la.add_node(40);
    la.add_node(50);

    la.display(la.gethead()); //10 20 30 40 50 

    la.del(la.gethead(), 40);
    la.display(la.gethead()); //10 20 30 50

    return 0;
}
```

I just want to know why the below code is not working.
I am trying to simplify the code by not using a double-pointer.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
    node* head;
    node* tail;
public:
    LinkedList()
    {
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
    }
    void add_node(int n)
    {
        node* temp = new node;
        temp->data = n;
        temp->next = nullptr;

        if(head == nullptr)
        {
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = temp;
            tail = tail->next;
        }
    }
    node* gethead()
    {
        return head;
    }
    void display(node * head)
    {
        if(head == nullptr)
        {
            cout << "nullptr : No data" << endl;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            node* temp;
            temp = head;
            while(temp != nullptr)
            {               
                cout << temp->data << endl;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }        
    }
     void del(node* head, int value)
    {       
        if(!head)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            node* pp = head;

            while((pp)->data != value)
                pp = pp->next;
            if(pp)
            {
                node* temp = pp;  
                pp = pp->next;
                delete temp;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "No matching data in the node" <<endl;
            }    
        }   
    }
};

int main()
{
    LinkedList la;
    la.add_node(10);
    la.add_node(20);
    la.add_node(30);
    la.add_node(40);
    la.add_node(50);

    la.display(la.gethead()); //10 20 30 40 50 

    la.del(la.gethead(), 40);
    la.display(la.gethead()); //10 20 30 50

    return 0;
}
```

Could you please give me advice about why the above code does not delete the node like the first code?
I think that the second code has to be worked because it deletes the node by utilizing pointer(which saves the address of the node).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By simplify, did you literally mean "delete one '*' from the code"?

Comment: pp and temp point to the same node which you delete.  You need to modify the previous node's next pointer (or the head if at the beginning) .

Comment: Explain "is not working". Why do you think it doesn't work? How does it not work. Does it have different behaviour from what you expected? What did you expect?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/DXunz58Q

Comment: @sweenish
Yes, My intention was using one '*' for the deletion function.

Comment: @eerorika
I will keep in mind your advice for the next time. Thanks. I updated the question based on your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the term is "Pointer to pointer" and not "double pointer". Double pointer is a pointer to a variable of type `double`.

You should really realize that pointers are simply addresses in your memory.
When you are copying pointer (i.e.: `node* pp = head;`), you put the address that head points to in pp.
What it means? that both pp and head are pointing to the same address.

But, it is also important to remember that pp and head are variables, and thus are written in the memory as well. Saying that - pp and head also have addresses, but since pp and head are distinct variables, they have distinct addresses.

So the problem comes when you are trying to modify the content of head.

On the first occurence:

```cpp
            node** nd = &head;
            while(*nd && (*nd)->data != value)
                nd = &(*nd)->next;
```

You don't modify the content of head (or `*nd`) at all. And thus, you could used the version with pp.

You problem is with this piece of code:

```cpp
pp = pp->next;
```

Here, pp is a copy of the address of the original linked list item, and since it is only a copy, then `pp = pp->next` does practicly nothing. In this case, you really should have written `*nd = *nd->next`, because this way change the original value and not a copy you created.

Note: even if you will change in your second example the variable `pp` to be a pointer-to-pointer, you code will still not be able to delete the first element in the list, since it is passed as a regular pointer to head, and thus only your first version is valid.

Comment: I understood your explanation. Thank you so much for the detail.  
As you mentioned, in the second code, `pp = pp->next` does practically nothing. Thanks for the point.  Moreover `delete temp` not deletes the node that I expected, but delete pp(which just saves the address of the node).  Thank you.